# MIPS basic lw query

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm working on an assignment where I'm trying to convert between C++ and MIPS, and I have a question that asks me to convert B[8] = A[i-3] i, A, and B  are stored in registries $s0, $s4, and $s5 respectively. The part I'm stuck on is how to store i-3 into A[]. Is it possible to do something like this?:

```
lw $t0, 32($s5)
addi $t1, $s0, -3
lw $t2, $t1($s4)
sw $t0, 0($t2)
```

I'm still a little bit new to MIPS and am mainly trying to figure out if you can use lw in that manner. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call `lw` with a register as the index. Assuming the values in the registers are correct, you need to perform it in two steps:

```
add $t1, $t1, $s4
lw $t2, 0($t1)
```

Do not forget that when accessing a word array, in which each element is 4 bytes long, you need to multiply the index by 4.